# DRF's not calling post() method when receiving POST request

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, post-redirect-get

I have a viewset like this:

```
class MyViewSet(CreateAPIView, RetrieveModelMixin, ListModelMixin, GenericViewSet):
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MySerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()

class MySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['id', 'field1', 'field2'] #only field1 is required in the model
```

The GET requests for list, and retrieve works perfectly. When I make a POST request, sending the `field1` I get a status 201 and a **new record is added to the database, so it works too**.

But my method `MyViewSet.post()` that should overwrite the same one from `generics.CreateAPIView` never gets called.

Not only that, but I've tried to add the `pdb.set_trace()`, literally inside the `generics.CreateAPIView.post()` and in the `CreateModelMixin.create()` functions and neither stopped once I made the POST request.

**So something else is handling this POST request and inserting into the DB, I just don't know what. And how can I overwrite it, so I can customize what should be done with a post request?**

PS.: Also, I don't think it's a routing problem, my `urls.py`:

```
from rest_framework import routers
from myapp.views import MyViewSet, AnotherViewSet

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'route_one', MyViewSet)
router.register(r'route_two', AnotherViewSet)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the exact class in order to use `POST` api.

```
class MyView(CreateModelMixin, ListModelMixin, generics.GenericAPIView):
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MySerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

In urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import MyView

urlpatterns = [
    path('route_one', MyView.as_view(), name="my_view_detail")   
]
```

Comment: Removing `GenericViewSet` and replacing it with `GenericAPIView` causes it to fail: `AttributeError: type object 'MyViewSet' has no attribute 'get_extra_actions'`. `get_extra_actions` seems to be called by the router.

Comment: To use `genericAPIView`, In urls.py you need to use `path` not `router`.

Comment: I'll change my answer.